# bootstrap 3 aligning items in their divs

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've been trying out bootstrap and have been having a hard time getting item'd to align in their divs.
i.e. in my fiddle I have a row up top that I'm trying to center the contents.(location/phone number)
Row 2 I'm trying to get it's list to form a row with the about shopper over to the side.

I've tried nav-row and a few other things. Can I get a pointer in the right direction; please :)

I've seen other questions similar but the one's I found didn't really help what I'm asking. Sorry if it's a duplicate.
[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Legion87/ezo9aqv2/1/)

```
  .footer .col-sm-3{
  overflow: hidden;
  }
  .footer-widget {
  margin-bottom: 68px;
  }

  .footer-widget .container {
  border-top: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
  padding-top: 15px;
  }

  .single-widget h2 {
  color: #666663;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin-bottom: 22px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  }

  .single-widget h2 i{
  margin-right:15px;
  }

  .single-widget ul li a{
  color: #8C8C88;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 300;
  padding: 5px 0;
  display:inline-block;
  }

  .single-widget ul li a i {
  margin-right: auto;
  }

  .single-widget ul li a:hover{
  background:none;
  color:#FE980F;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap uses 12 columns, meaning that e.g.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">I'm the left half</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">I'm the right half</div>
</div>
```

In your first row you use `col-sm-2` which is only 1/6 of the screen. To center align you don't really need bootstrap, just do `text-align:center` in css. It's possible that only parts of your document have rows/columns, so I would leave away the first one if you just want to center.

For the second part, you just need to increase the size of the jsfiddle box and it will align next to each other. But again, you should use something that sums up to twelve.

Here is an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/6u4cj25h/

Notice how I replaced `sm` by `xs`, meaning that the columns won't collapse even on small screens.

Comment: Now that's what I was looking for thank you. All the other explanations were long winded and hard to follow. Can I ask what does the xs mean in terms of bootstrap? Haven't seen it yet.

Comment: The xs means the colums will never collapse, not even on mobile. If you use sm, above screen size 750px the columns will be aligned next to each other and below screen size 750px the columns will be aligned on top of each other. If you choose xs the columns will stay aligned next to each other even for screen sizes smaller than 750. Also see http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options.